# Turtles getting stucked at the edge when not wrapped horizontally and vertically

Tags: netlogo

I have my turtles go around randomly in my world. The problem is, I unwrapped it horizontally and vertically. I dont want to wrap it, but instead i just want it to bounce back if it reaches the border.Thank you very much.

Comment: you need to provide the code that actually moves the turtles if you want us to work out why they aren't moving

Comment: check out the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library, e.g. Bounce Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turtles have a variable `heading` indicating their direction in grades. If you don't want your turtle to keep going that way, you need to change that variable. So, I suggest that you use the variable `heading`and add 180 (forcing the turtle to turn around). Something like:

```
ask turtles [ 
  if (xcor = minxcor or ycor = minycor or xcor = maxxcor or ycor = maxycor) 
  [
    set heading heading + 180
  ]
]
```

where minxcor, minycor, maxxcor, maxycor are your bounds (depending on where your axis is situated: you can check that on the interface properties). So you're saying is: if you reach the end of the world, turn back. You can decide the grades, not necessarily 180. If you want to keep heading between 0 and 360 you can simply write `set heading (heading + 180) mod 360`.

If you have any doubt about what I've just written, feel free to ask!

Comment: This really helped a lot. Thank you very much